# How to change $array[x[y]] to $array[x][y]

Tags: php, arrays

How to change the array:

```
$array['db[blabla]']
```

to this array:

```
$array['db']['blabla']
```

Thanks.

Comment: How did you get `$array['db[blabla]']`?

Comment: `$array['db']['blabla'] = $array['db[blabla]']; unset($array['db[blabla]']);`

Comment: @MarkBaker Good caught, but how did he got: `$array['db[blabla]']` ?

Comment: I cant do it, because string 'db[blabla]' is inside a variable.

Comment: @Upimform Just show us the entire script (How you got this array with the key)! Otherwise this will get chatty

Comment: I put db[blabla] in input name, and save the input name inside variable.

Comment: This whole example is incorrect probably trying to make it simple for us readers. Please post your original code instead of this `blabla`

Comment: I just want to know how to change db[xxx] from string to array $db[xxx]?

Comment: We are trying to help you do what makes sense not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my crack at it (tested)

```
$array['db[blabla]'] = 10;
$newArr = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $r = explode("[",$key);
    $newArr[$r[0]][str_replace(']', '', $r[1])] = $value;
}
```

Comment: @Rizier123 not sure what you mean by brain buffer, but the code is now tested.